# Как закрасить ячейку в QCalendarWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcalendarwidget

Как закрасить определённую ячейку (дату) в `QCalendarWidget`?

Я читал документацию и нашёл функцию:

```
paintCell(painter, rect, date) 

где:
    painter – QPainter

    rect – QRect

    date – QDate
```

Но так и не понял как её использовать. Можете показать пример кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QRectF, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QColor, QFont, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication

class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        if date == QDate(2020, 6, 12):
            painter.save()
            self.brush = QBrush(Qt.Dense6Pattern)  
            self.brush.setColor(Qt.red)
            painter.setBrush(self.brush)
            painter.drawRect(rect)
            
            painter.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
            painter.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 10))            
            painter.drawText(QRectF(rect), Qt.TextSingleLine|Qt.AlignCenter, str(date.day()))
            painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignCenter, 'Hello\nWorld') 
            painter.restore()
        else:
            QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: Хотя у меня есть вопрос?  У меня уже есть календарь как часть MainWindow  и я инициализирую его при запуске приложения. Могу ли я рисовать на нём?

Comment: @Veter_ok Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.