# QCalendarWidget: изменить фон конкретного дня

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qcalendarwidget

Работаю под PyQt5, возникла проблема с тем, чтобы изменить фон для конкретного одного дня, другими словами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой из постов отвечает на ваш вопрос ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140261/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-qcalendarwidget/1140289#1140289  ,  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141033/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-qcalendarwidget-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8/1141083#1141083

Comment: Буквально минутой ранее я нашел ответ на свой вопрос из вопроса по первой ссылке. Пока не разобрался как закрасить полностью. Спасибо!